# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Project Broken

Tags: .net-4.5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-dynamic-data

Can anybody get ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web project working under EF 6.0.2 and .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013?

I find problems in ManyToMany_Edit.ascx.cs and Global.asax.cs all relating to the switch in namespace for ObjectContext. Changing the using statements in the generated files is not enough. In other words, following this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466) is not enough.

System.Web.DynamicData.dll doesn't seem to be aware of System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.

Comment: Found this [link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/434936)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this post? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx , this works for me